# Table tennis simulator

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-loops

I edited my previous question because I came up with the code I think is correct. 
The logic behind this should be: 
while the set is not over and it's not a tie 10:10: player A starts serving and does it twice regardless he wins points or not, then player B takes serve and does it twice also. It continues until the set is over, except there is a tie 10:10 when servers change each point scored.

Can anyone check if the code is flawless? thank you.

```
def simOneSet(probA, probB):
    serving = "A"
    scoreA = scoreB = 0
    while not setOver(scoreA, scoreB):
        if scoreA != 10 and scoreB != 10:
            if serving == "A":
                for i in range(2):
                    if random() < probA:
                        scoreA += 1
                    else:
                        scoreB += 1
                serving = "B"
            else:
                for i in range(2):
                    if random() < probB:
                        scoreB +=1
                    else:
                        scoreA += 1
                serving = "A"    
        # when there is a tie 10:10
        else:
            if serving == "A":
                if random() < probA:
                    scoreA += 1
                    serving = "B"
                else:
                    scoreB += 1
                    serving = "B"
            else:
                if random() < probB:
                    scoreB += 1
                    serving = "B"
                else:
                    scoreA += 1
                    serving = "A"
    return scoreA, scoreB
```

Comment: I just edited the code and request, can anyone follow it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a dict to "switch" between players:

```
other = {'A':'B', 'B':'A'}
```

Then, if `serving` equals `'A'`, then `other[serving]` would equal `'B'`, and if `serving` equals `'B'`, then `other[serving]` would equal `'A'`.

---

You could also use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to keep track of the score:

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: score = collections.Counter()

In [3]: score['A'] += 1

In [4]: score['A'] += 1

In [5]: score['B'] += 1

In [6]: score
Out[6]: Counter({'A': 2, 'B': 1})
```

---

Also notice how in this piece of code

```
    if serving == "A":
        for i in range(2):
            if random() < probA:
                scoreA += 1
            else:
                scoreB += 1
    else:
        for i in range(2):
            if random() < probB:
                scoreB +=1
            else:
                scoreA += 1
```

there are two blocks which are basically the same idea repeated twice. That's a sign that the code can be tightened-up by using a function. For example, we could define a function `serve` which when given a probability `prob` and a player (`A` or `B`) returns the player who wins:

```
def serve(prob, player):
    if random.random() < prob:
        return player
    else:
        return other[player]
```

then the above code would become

```
    for i in range(2):
        winner = serve(prob[serving], serving)
        score[winner] += 1
```

---

Thus, you can compactify your code quite a bit this way:

```
import random
import collections
other = {'A':'B', 'B':'A'}

def serve(prob, player):
    if random.random() < prob:
        return player
    else:
        return other[player]

def simOneSet(probA, probB):
    prob = {'A':probA, 'B':probB}
    score = collections.Counter()

    serving = "A"
    while not setOver(score['A'], score['B']):
        for i in range(2):
            winner = serve(prob[serving], serving)
            score[winner] += 1
        if score['A'] == 10 and score['B'] == 10:
            winner = serve(prob[serving], serving)
            score[winner] += 1
            serving = winner

    return score['A'], score['B']  

def setOver(scoreA, scoreB):
    return max(scoreA, scoreB) >= 21

print(simOneSet(0.5,0.5))
```

Comment: thanks a million. Your post might go slightly over my head cuz I haven't yet leant nothing about dictionaries and correlations but it's OK I'll back to your post when I catch up a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint:

If you have the roundnumber in the set and know which player started serving, you have everything you need to know who is serving.

Then a simple if statement at the start or end of your loop should be enough.

If this is too complicated, try starting by simulating a game where the server starts every round.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help is the syntax

```
var = 1 if var == 2 else 2
```

Which will make var be 1 if var is 2, and var be 2 if var is 1.  I feel as though this is a school problem, so I don't want to totally give away the answer :)

Hint: You're on the right track with your thinking.

Comment: Thanks, it is not a piece of homework though. I'm learning with Zelle's Programming Python that's why :)

Comment: I am glad to hear that you are learning python!  If you need more help just leave a comment and I can update my answer to be more explanatory.

Comment: Hi William, at first I did not get your hint code, but it just dawned on me right now and used it to change who serves next function after a set is over. thank you Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

from random import *

```
P1=P2=0

while 1 :

  p1=p2=0

  while 2 :

    if random() < 0.5 : p1 +=1

    else              : p2 +=1


    if(p1 >=11 or p2 >=11) and abs(p1-p2) > 1: break

  P1 += p1 > p2; P2 += p2 > p1

  print "%2d : %2d (%d : %d)" % (p1, p2, P1, P2)

  if P1 == 4 or P2 == 4 : break
```

i hope this helps, it worked for me